# Check string is valid date in Carbon with overflow and relative format flags

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

I need a method like this:

```
function check_date_format($date, $allowOverflow = false, $allowRelativeFormats = false)
```

which was return bool if string is correct date/time according to the boolean flags.

Where `$allowOverflow = false` means dates that are overflow like 2020-13-13 (2021-01-13) are not correct,
and `$allowRelativeFormats = false` means that relative dates like 'today', 'tomorow' 'x day ago' etc. are incorrect

There is any possibility to write that functions using Carbon / DateTime class without defining own arrays like `$availableFormats` inside this function?

Examples to understood my expected result:

```
check_date_format('asdgasd'); // false
check_date_format('2020-02-01'); // true
check_date_format('2020-02-30'); // false
check_date_format('2020-02-30', true); // true
check_date_format('10:00'); // true
check_date_format('tomorrow'); // false
check_date_format('tomorrow', false, true); // true
check_date_format('now'); // false
```

I tried to use `date_parse()` in such way:

```
function check_date_format($date, $allowOverflow = false, $allowRelativeFormats = false)
{
    $dateInfo = date_parse($date);
    $isCorrectDate = $dateInfo['error_count'] === 0;
    if ($isCorrectDate) {
        $isRelative = array_key_exists('relative', $dateInfo);
        $isOverflowed = $dateInfo['warning_count'] > 0;

        if (!$allowOverflow && $isOverflowed) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$allowRelativeFormats && ($isRelative || strtolower(trim($date)) === 'now')) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

but this solution assumes that 'warnings' means overflows which I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Checking if a date can be created can be done by simply trying it:

```php
try {
    $date = @Carbon::parse('asdgasd');
} catch (InvalidFormatException $_) {
    $date = false;
}

$canBeCreated = ($date !== false);
```

Checking if a string is a relative format is supported out of the box by Carbon:

```php
$hasRelativeFormat = Carbon::hasRelativeKeywords('tomorrow');
```

But for the overflow, there is no way that could handle all formats at once. For instance if you have strict format input you can check overflow happened or not:

```php
Carbon::parse('2020-02-01')->format('Y-m-d') === '2020-02-01'; // true => no overflow
Carbon::parse('2020-02-30')->format('Y-m-d') === '2020-02-30'; // false => overflow
```

But this trick is no longer possible if `"January 1st 2020"` is allowed. And the overflow actually happen inside PHP timelib extension (inside `new DateTime()` constructor), this behavior is not part of the library code, so it's on your business-side code to decide what input to allow if you want to restrict it and decide how to detect an overflow happened.

Generally speaking, it can be safer not to mix all those checks in one single function with a matrix of boolean flags making various combinations of checks, I would rather keep them separated.

Comment: Your overflows solution assumed that i always have day, month and year.

Comment: That exactly what I said in my answer and I explained precisely why this is a requirement.

Comment: `Carbon::parse` cannot be trusted to validate a date. `12/13/1990` will parse... but it may be in `d/m/Y` format. Even if you use `createFromFormat` Carbon will still parse the date instead of giving an error.